# aria2c protocol error with download directory

Tags: aria2

I am trying to us aria2 to download some large files and getting below protocol error that I can not seem to fix. Thank you :).

```
aria2c -x 3 -c -d -l mydir --http-user "xxx" --http-passwd "xxx" xxx://www.xxx.com/xx/xxx/xxx/filename
Exception caught
Exception: [download_helper.cc:403] errorCode=1 Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: mydir
```

I also tried putting in the exact path for the downloads to go:

```
aria2c -x 3 -c -d -l /home/cmccabe/Desktop/xxx/xxx/xxx --http-user "xxx" --http-passwd "xxx" xxx://www.xxx.com/xx/xx/xxxx/filename
Exception caught
Exception: [download_helper.cc:403] errorCode=1 Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your download directory should be a parameter after -d (which is the Directory command) instead of placing after -l (which is for Log).